# I need to execute a curl request using php

Tags: php, curl, get

Here is a query on the command line that works.

How can I get an answer to this request using PHP in the script?

```
curl -X GET   https://megaservice.com/api/abonents   -H 'X-AUTH-TOKEN: xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx' -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Comment: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://megaservice.com/api/abonents",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(

    "X-AUTH-TOKEN: xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx",
    "cache-control: no-cache,no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cUrl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
$channel = curl_init('https://megaservice.com/api/abonents');
curl_setopt_array($channel, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // Return curl-data to variable
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'X-AUTH-TOKEN: xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx',
        'cache-control: no-cache',
    ],
]);
$result = curl_exec($channel);

curl_close($channel); // Important thing - close channel for not load your server

var_dump($result); // Here's your result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post or get like this with curl,

```
function post($url, $data, $headerArray = ["Content-type:application/json;charset='utf-8'","Accept:application/json"])
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if ($headerArray){
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headerArray);
    }

    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $output;
}

function get($url,$userpwd = "",$headerArray = ["Content-type:application/json;charset='utf-8'","Accept:application/json"]){

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if($userpwd) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
    }
    if($headerArray){
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headerArray);
    }
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $output;
}
```